# Front camera is not inverting photos on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera

I have very typical custom camera implementation. I'm using `Camera.takePicture(...)` method to take photos. And usually photos that are taken using front camera are horizontally inverted (mirrored). I'm totally fine with it, but I've noticed that on some devices it's not true and photos are not inverted. I would like to have a consistent behavior for all devices. So is there a way to know whether a photo is not inverted?

Comment: On my device just the preview is flipped, the photo itself isn't. I guess this is for people using the phone as mirror.

Comment: I guess that mirrored picture is a bug.

Comment: @Henry however on some devices photos look same as on preview. So I'm wondering if there's a way to determine this behaviour

Comment: @AlexCohn, might be but instagram camera works in the same way on all devices, so I would like to know how they do it.

Comment: *[Instagram image size used to be 612px by 612px but then switched to 640px by 640px and on July 2015 switched to 1080px by 1080px](https://colorlib.com/wp/size-of-the-instagram-picture/)*. I believe that Instagram camera captures a preview frame; frames received in **onPreviewFrame()** callback are never rotated or mirrored.

Comment: @AlexCohn, it makes sense, what about video then? looks like they use default MediaRecorder, so they don't have any control over original video file

Comment: You don't need to control the video file to guarantee proper rotation. Even with MediaRecorder, they have control over the camera.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I'm a little confused. When I record a video with front camera, the result video is mirrored comparing to preview. But as I said before on some devices the result video is not mirrored. So obviously instagram does some post-processing to invert those videos manually. And to do so they must know if the video is not mirrored automatically.

Comment: Your original question concerned **takePicture()**, IIRC. I believe you that **MediaRecorder** mirrors the video for front camera for some devices. I would be surprised if all devices that save the picture mirrored, also save the video mirrored. At any rate, you can use MediaCodec with preview frames to keep full control

Comment: @AlexCohn, seems like not much I can do without reworking current camera solution. Anyway thanks!